# Keeping a video fit to a place with respect to the background

Tags: css

I have an image which has a television screen in the middle. I want to place a YouTube video in the middle of the screen after choosing the image as the background. The current code makes it possible but it does not work fine with different browsers. Please guide. Thanks

```
<div style="
position:relative;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  background: url(img/backround2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

">
<iframe style="position:absolute; margin-top:12.7%;margin-left:31%; width:41.1%; height:43%;" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/VIDEO_ID?portrait=0&color=333"  frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: "The current code" needs to be posted or else how can we help you?

Comment: With HTML you can specify the location of the <div></div> using a CSS style="top: 100px; left: 10px;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Paint, find the number of pixels there are from the top of the background image to the top of the TV  in the background image.  This is your topDistance.

Again using Paint, find the number of pixels there are from the left of the background image to the left of the TV in the background image.  This is your leftDistance.

Now, apply these CSS rules to the video container `<div>`:

```
position: absolute;
top: (topDistance)px; /* replace (topDistance) with the distance you found earlier*/
left: (leftDistance)px; /* replace (leftDistance) with the distance you found earlier */
```

Sample:

```
div.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

where the video is placed 100px from the top of the browser and 50px from the left of the browser.  Make sure to use pixels in this case because different browsers will interpret % distances differently, depending on your parent `div`s and the window size.

Take the parent `div` that contains the background image and apply a `position: relative;` rule.  Although `position: relative;` keeps the `div`'s behavior the same, it allows you to put the video in relation to the `div`.  Consider your options for height/width of the `div`, and the background-size, as well: the browsers' interpretation of %/cover for those tags, respectively, depends on its parent `div`s and the window size as well.  Sometimes the browsers do unexpected things with %/cover and inheritance.

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RoyalleBlue/6D87p/1/)

Comment: I tried this too but It was still displaying differently in different browsers. Moreover on a zoom in or out, this wouldnt work.